# How to incorporate functions within Do Loops

Tags: algorithm, list-manipulation

I'm attempting to repeatedly perform a simple algorithm with incremental changes of a parameter.

I can easily express my changing parameter:

```
Do[a[n] = (10/180*Pi + n/180*Pi);
Print[a[n]], {n, 0, 70, 1}];
```

Here is what I wish to do for each iteration:

```
sol = 
NDSolve[{y''[t] == -10 - 0.3*(Sin[a]), 
y'[0] == 12*Sin[a], y[0] == 0}, y[t], t];
h[t_]=y[t]/.sol;

FindMaximum[h[t],{t,2}]
```

I think I need to define sol[n_] and incorporate it into a Table function:

```
sol[n_]= ??
sol2[n_]=FindMaximum[sol[n],{t,2}]    
m = Table[{a[n], sol2[n]}, {n, (Pi*10/180), (Pi*80/
180, Pi/180}];
```

But this is where I've been stuck for a while. Even a greatly simplified example would be very helpful.

Comment: You might find this useful: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/8

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you can, you should be using `Map[]` instead of tables:

```
k =FindMaximum[y@t/.NDSolve[{y''[t] == -10 - 3/10  Sin@#, y'[0] == 12 Sin@#, y[0] == 0},
                            y[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}], {t, 2}]  & /@ (Pi/180 Range[10, 80])
```

Now, plotting the max vs t:

```
ListPlot[{t /. #[[2]], #[[1]]} & /@ k]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, the max vs n:

```
ListPlot[k[[All, 1]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Create a list of the changing parameter:

```
a = Pi/180 * Range[10,80]
```

Now for the NDSolve

```
 sol = Table[NDSolve[{y''[t] == -10 - 0.3 Sin[a[[i]]], y'[0] == 12 Sin[a[[i]]], 
    y[0] == 0}, y[t], t], {i, 1, Length[a]}] // Flatten
```

You'll then get the solutions as a list.